# Pasting HTML formatted text in Pages.app on macOS increases the font size

Tags: macos, pages, copy-paste, formatting, html

I'm writing a Java program that copies HTML formatted text to the clipboard. A short example of how I'm doing this is viewable at this Stack Overflow question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971841/write-contents-of-jtextpane-to-clipboard-using-htmleditorkit-without-extra-space

However, for some reason when I paste the text into Pages, the formatting is all correct except that Pages automatically increases the font size. In my above example, all text is formatted using `<span>` elements to have a specified font size of 13 pt. However, the resulting text in Pages has a font size of 17.33 pt. It certainly is not hard to just manually change the font size of what I just pasted. But perhaps there is a way to change this behavior?